# Vim-surround with "onemore"

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-surround

I have the following setting on:

```
set ve+=onemore "allows us to go one-past the last character, emulating ctrl-e in normal programs
```

This is helpful for a lot of navigations and other commands I use. However, when I use vim-surround and highlight an entire line (for example, doing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>), it ends up going to the next line in surround:

[image]

Is there a way to customize or apply an option to vim-surround such that when highlighting a line, it doesn't continue onto the next? Note: this is fixed, when I do something like <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to compensate for the "onemore" option, but this is quite annoying to have to do everytime. What might be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I use `yss` more often than `VS`; however, even without `onemore` set, I get this behavior. From `:help surround`:

```
In visual mode, a simple "S" with an argument wraps the selection.  This is
referred to as the *vS* mapping, although ordinarily there will be
additional keystrokes between the v and S.  In linewise visual mode, the
surroundings are placed on separate lines and indented.  In blockwise visual
mode, each line is surrounded.
```

`yss` won't do this and is easier to type.

Comment: @D -- I see, but that grabs the full-line instead of often I'll just want to do something until the end of the line. Here's an example with css: https://gyazo.com/59d16ac11e3144bfb3ca2e300e509054.

Comment: If you need to end of line, you're stuck with, e.g., `ys$` @David542

Comment: @D -- that works. Is there a way to do that in visual mode too (non linewise), here's an example of what I mean (though note I'm using the `h` after going to the end of the line): https://gyazo.com/4e0724bdc9070d6d2127cb6a10efc8fc.

Comment: I just tried your example (`set ve=onemore`, then select `v$` and type `S"`), and I got the "expected" behavior sans `h` (that is, it surrounded what I expected to, despite the wonky visual selection)

Comment: Hmm...in that case, is there a way when I press `S` that if in the visual mode and I'm to to-the-right of the last `\S` character, that it does an `h` automatically. to move me over to the last character?

Comment: @And of course -- thanks for all your help with your answer and comments.

Comment: I didn't see anything at a quick glance, no @David542